# Why does Skillicorn's Taxonomy allow us to design 30 models?

Tags: computer-architecture

In Skillcorn, David B, "[A Taxonomy for Computer Architectures](http://service.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/5105/papers/intro/skillicorn_survey.pdf)", *IEEE Computer*, 21(11):46-57, Nov 1988, a taxonomy of multiprocessor architectures is described.

My teacher said that Skillikorn's Taxonomy allows us to design 30 different models, but only 7(9?) of them are reasonable.

What did he mean by that?

Comment: I would suggest asking him.

Comment: I added a reference and pointer to the paper (which I'd never heard of before).  Might your teacher be talking about Table 1 on Page 54?